# Spring SmartValidator in unit test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, validation

I think I don't understand what really happens in background when I use the SmartValidator interface for entity validation.

I would like to test my entity class and check for correct validation by providing testcases with invalid attribute content. Unfortunately the SmartValidator, that gets autowired into the service class (which works if I run the application as spring boot app), is null during "maven test".

I don't want to mock the validation errors, I want to check if the annotations in the entity are set correctly and perform a real validation during the test.
=> How can I validate in this way during test?

Thanks

My service class:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;

@Service
class EstateService {

    @AutoWired
    private SmartValidator validator;

    public void create(Estate e) {
        BindingResult br = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(e, e.getClass().getName());
        validator.validate(e, br);

        // ...
        // encapsulate found validation errors grouped by attributes... the reason why
        // I don't just use @Valid Estate e in the function call
    }


}
```

The entity class:

```java
@Entity
class Estate {
    
    // ...

    @Size(max = 32)
    private String name;    

    // ...
}
```